How to install sk1 on macOS?
I want to try sk1 as a graphic design app. I found the GitHub repository for macOS, cloned it, and follow the steps mentioned in the sibling directory for Linux to install:
git clone https://github.com/sk1project/build-macos
cd build-macos
sudo python3 setup.py build

and I get this error in the build log:
Making install in gdbus-2.0/codegen
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
 /opt/local/bin/gmkdir -p '/opt/uniconvertor/bin'
 /opt/local/bin/ginstall -c gdbus-codegen '/opt/uniconvertor/bin'
 /opt/local/bin/gmkdir -p '/opt/uniconvertor/share/glib-2.0/codegen'
 /opt/local/bin/ginstall -c -m 644 __init__.py codegen.py codegen_main.py codegen_docbook.py config.py dbustypes.py parser.py utils.py '/opt/uniconvertor/share/glib-2.0/codegen'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
make[6]: *** [install-codegenPYTHON] Error 1
make[5]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[4]: *** [install] Error 2
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2

I tried installing imp with PIP but the package is missing in Python 3.12.4. Apparently it was deprecated in 3.12, but it is also missing from pip in 3.11.10 and 3.10.15.
How can I install sk1 on macOS?

From the Linux repository of sk1:

Please note that application uses Python 2.x version. So Python interpreter and python based dependencies should be for 2.x, but not 3.x

These projects haven't seen any update in the last five years, you may need to port it to Python 3 first.
